# Standard way of determining placement of window frame controls

Tags: linux, windows, electron, cross-platform, abstraction

## The More General Question

I am wondering if there is a standard way that operating systems / desktop managers use to expose the user's preference regarding the placement of the window frame controls (Close, Maximize/Miniaturize, Minimize).

For platforms like Windows and MacOS, it's "pretty" safe to assume that the users wants their window controls on the right and left respectively to match the rest of the windows in the GUI. But the key word here is "**assume**'. I hate to assume things when I code.

Furthermore, what about all the different Linux distributions and flavors?

I think this information could be useful to application developers in the same way that it's useful to know the user's preferences regarding dark or light themes.

## My More Specific Question

Now, what I'm building currently is an Electron application that could really benefit from a custom title bar (a.k.a. a frameless window). And I do understand that my problem is caused by the fact that I want to bypass the window frame abstraction that is normally offered by the operating systems, but I'd really like to be able to position my custom controls in my title bar without having to guess.

But anyway, since I use Electron, I do have access to native features using NodeJS, but I'd also be curious to know if browsers have or are planning to implement a way for the CSS or JavaScript running in the browser to determine the intended placement of the window controls, again, similarly to [prefers-color-scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme)?

Comment: Why would this be needed in a browser? Generally, browser vendors refrain from adding too much OS information as every little bit may be used to fingerprint users and track them throughout the internet. Also, I'd be surprised if there was a standard exposing which side the window controls are on on Linux. (KWin from KDE also allows them to be placed arbitrarily on the title bar...) You're dealing with numerous window managers and thus the safest bet could be a Freedesktop specification, but so far I have found none. What about letting your users decide which way they want the title bar to be?

Comment: Well come to think of it, it's true that browser vendors will probably want to avoid that, but I was thinking along the lines of if an app developper wanted to build some kind of modal or tab system within his app it could have been useful.

For my project, I have a feeling that I will probably end up making an educated guess and letting my user choose which way they want it with a setting.

Things like KWin from KDE are exactly what I had in mind. If there was a standard way, at least on Linux, for window managers to expose information like that at 'runtime' it'd be great.

Comment: I'll look up Freedesktop, I don't know what that is!